# How do I rename many files from whatever to sequential filenames?

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I have a directory with 8,000 images.  These have a variety of filenames and are of type jpeg or png.

I want to rename them to:

```
pic00001.png
pic00002.jpg
```

I don't mind if I end up doing the pngs in one run and the jpegs in another, ending up with two slightly overlapping sets - pic00001.png, pic00002.png and pic00001.jpeg, pic00002.jpeg

Current questions on SE cover bulk renaming if you take the existing file name and add or remove static information. I'm not doing that. I am replacing the entire filename with an incrementing number.

Comment: You just want to number the files in some random order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a shell loop like:

```
for f in *.jpeg *.png
do  printf "mv '%s' pic%05d.%s \n" "$f" $((++c)) "${f##*.}"
done | sh
```

This program creates a single sequence with one run of a serial number and retains the original file extension.

Note: The technique to create the commands or command sequences and piping the result in a shell is a standard coding pattern. You can run the program first without the final pipe into `sh` to inspect whether the created commands fit, and if everything looks fine append the final pipe. (As opposed to adding temporarily an `echo` (as often seen) the pipe-into-shell method creates **consistent** output.)

But note (as Gilles poined out) that in the given case a file name containing single quotes will create for the respective file name a wrong result. If you don't need the pre-inspection facility you can directly execute the commands, as in:

```
for f in *.jpeg *.png
do
  ((++c))
  new_f=$( printf "pic%05d.%s" $c "${f##*.}" )
  mv "${f}" "${new_f}"
done
```

(For the paranoid: Of course there can always be situations where those solutions also don't work as intended; e.g. if some of the existing files conform already to the target file name format; in this case you would, e.g., create/move the files to a new temporary directory to avoid the corruption of the respective files.)

Comment: Piping data into `sh` is tricky and hardly ever useful. Your script breaks if a file name contains a single quote. Why are you doing this? It would be simpler and less buggy to call `mv` instead of printing out an `mv` command.

Comment: @Gilles; I disagree with you. Creating shell commands and piping those into a shell is often rather **very** useful. - You can omit the shell pipe to inspect whether commands are correctly created before actually running them. (Which, BTW, could also be done in case of specific the `'` character that you spotted.)